# Post/update data via twitter API

Tags: php, twitter

What I have:
Twitter app created at twitter and PHP app at localhost

What I want:
post tweets/update statuses via twitter API from only(!) the app account. 
No twitter@anywhere, no user login, nothing fancy.

What I tried:

https://github.com/abraham/twitteroauth with access tokens from the dev.twitter.com website, returned

> "POST data is not available with this
>   token"

or something like that.

code snippet I found on some website:

```
// Define credentials for the Twitter account
define('TWITTER_CREDENTIALS', 'username:password');


// Set up CURL with the Twitter URL and some options
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://twitter.com/statuses/update.xml?status=test_status');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT, 2);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);


// Twitter uses HTTP authentication, so tell CURL to send our Twitter account details
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, TWITTER_CREDENTIALS);


// Execute the curl process and then close
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);


// If nothing went wrong, we should now have some XML data 
echo '<pre>'.htmlentities(print_r($data, true)).'</pre>';
```

returned

> "Basic authentication is not
>   supported"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay I've found what's the problem.

By default, Twitter sets all apps to read-only, so even when you login via PHP, you can't send POST/UPDATE. What you need to do is go to your application settings (the one where you set app name, description and avatar) and before avatar there's a "default access type", switch it to

> Read, Write, & Direct Messages

and voila.

to test the app use this snippet

```
$twitter = new \TwitterOAuth('consumer_key', 'consumer_secret', 
                              '(oauth_token', 'oauth_token_secret');
$twitter->get('account/verify_credentials');
$twitter->post('statuses/update', array('status' => 'test status'));
```

Oh and you don't need to do the login stuff with your app, you get the required tokens under "My access Token" menu.

Answer (score 1):

That big code snippet uses basic authentication, which is no longer supported by Twitter. Disregard it.

OAuth is now required by Twitter instead, which is what abraham's twitteroauth library uses. You *will* have to log in/authenticate using this, at least once.

You will also have to first [register your app with Twitter](https://dev.twitter.com/apps/new), to receive your own Consumer Key and Consumer Secret. Then you'll be able to start using Twitter's API via twitteroauth.

Comment: yes I have registered my app with Twitter, can't use twitteroauth without those keys. When you go to settings panel of an app you also get the tokens for app.